# Command error by running "fastboot oem unlock"

Tags: applications, rooting, adb, root-access, fastboot

I am unable to use the following command on an **HTC One M7**

```
# fastboot oem unlock 
...
(bootloader) [ERR] Command error !!!
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
```

**Why do I get this error and how to unlock my bootloader?**

In addition

```
# fastboot flashing unlock
...
FAILED (remote: not allowed)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

Comment: What device (and Android version) do you have? Without further information we can't know for sure why you're getting that message. It's possible that you need to use `fastboot flashing unlock` instead as this is the new version of the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't unlock an HTC phone like this - in fact most phones can't.

Provided yours is unlockable (i.e. not an AT&T/Verizon variant), you need to sign up and apply for unlock [here](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader) and use the token you acquired to complete the unlock process. The site itself will walk you through thoroughly.